# Blueimp File Upload: multiple selection on popup

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'am using Blueimp Jquery File Upload

i have problem when cancel an image in collection of pic,
all pic will close too

this is occured while i select multiple files in one popup

anyone ever struggling with this problem ?
i don't know if this is bugs / or something capability

update:
this happened when i set singleFileUploads false

[multiple selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6rtz.png)

[button start and cancel disappear for second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVO2w.png)

Answer (score 0):

i don't think this is a bug. I have also implemented without any problem. The problem might be due to wrong implementation of template.
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Template-Engine

Comment: this happened when i set singleFileUploads: False